# Block write access in a specific folder

Tags: blocking, write-protect

I guess you are all aware of Bettersurf that keeps getting in computers and its almost impossible to find how?

Well, I want to get rid of it and only deleting its file does not fix the problem, it keeps coming back.

So I would like to know how I can prevent ANY software to write in the bettersurf folder. I will still delete the files inside but keep the folder so it wont disapear and block the write access in that folder

Im running Windows 7

So thank you if you can give me a nice answer

Comment: Windows? Linux,Android OSX, OS/2?

Comment: Windows 7, im editing the question to add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are an administrator (and am assuming you are) then most likely not. Might recommend that you create a file with the name of the directory after removing the directory. This "should" prevent the directory from being created, unless they remove it and then create it. However, they may also just bypass by creating another different directory. Best cure is to find the cause of it being there (check task manager and boot to see if process is there that is creating it).